# Implementing single-precision division as double-precision multiplication

Tags: c, floating-point, c99, compiler-optimization, ieee-754

### Question

For a C99 compiler implementing exact IEEE 754 arithmetic, do values of `f`, `divisor` of type `float` exist such that `f / divisor != (float)(f * (1.0 / divisor))`?

EDIT: By “implementing exact IEEE 754 arithmetic” I mean a compiler that rightfully defines FLT_EVAL_METHOD as 0.

### Context

A C compiler that provides IEEE 754-compliant floating-point can only replace a single-precision division by a constant by a single-precision multiplication by the inverse if said inverse is itself representable exactly as a `float`.

In practice, this only happens for powers of two. So a programmer, Alex, may be confident that `f / 2.0f` will be compiled as if it had been `f * 0.5f`, but if it is acceptable for Alex to multiply by `0.10f` instead of dividing by 10, Alex should express it by writing the multiplication in the program, or by using a compiler option such as GCC's `-ffast-math`.

This question is about transforming a single-precision division into a double-precision multiplication. Does it always produce the correctly rounded result? Is there a chance that it  could be cheaper, and thus be an optimization that compilers might make (even without `-ffast-math`)?

I have compared `(float)(f * 0.10)` and `f / 10.0f` for all single-precision values of `f` between 1 and 2, without finding any counter-example. This should cover all divisions of normal `float`s producing a normal result.

Then I generalized the test to all divisors with the program below:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  for (float divisor = 1.0; divisor != 2.0; divisor = nextafterf(divisor, 2.0))
    {
      double factor = 1.0 / divisor; // double-precision inverse
      for (float f = 1.0; f != 2.0; f = nextafterf(f, 2.0))
        {
          float cr = f / divisor;
          float opt = f * factor; // double-precision multiplication
          if (cr != opt)
            printf("For divisor=%a, f=%a, f/divisor=%a but (float)(f*factor)=%a\n",
                   divisor, f, cr, opt);
        }
    }
}
```

The search space is just large enough to make this interesting (2<sup>46</sup>). The program is currently running. Can someone tell me whether it will print something, perhaps with an explanation why or why not, before it has finished?

Comment: Or we could all switch to Spivak pronouns: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spivak_pronoun

Comment: Note that your program might run faster using `+=FLT_EPSILON` instead of `nextafterf`.

Comment: @R.. Good point, I just checked and both `gcc -O2` and `clang -O2` generate the function call for `nextafterf()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your program won't print anything, assuming round-ties-to-even rounding mode.  The essence of the argument is as follows:

We're assuming that both `f` and `divisor` are between `1.0` and `2.0`.  So `f = a / 2^23` and `divisor = b / 2^23` for some integers `a` and `b` in the range `[2^23, 2^24)`.  The case `divisor = 1.0` isn't interesting, so we can further assume that `b > 2^23`.

The only way that `(float)(f * (1.0 / divisor))` could give the wrong result would be for the exact value `f / divisor` to be so close to a halfway case (i.e., a number exactly halfway between two single-precision floats) that the accumulated errors in the expression `f * (1.0 / divisor)` push us to the *other side* of that halfway case from the true value.

But that can't happen.  For simplicity, let's first assume that `f >= divisor`, so that the exact quotient is in `[1.0, 2.0)`.  Now any halfway case for single precision in the interval `[1.0, 2.0)` has the form `c / 2^24` for some odd integer `c` with `2^24 < c < 2^25`.  The exact value of `f / divisor` is `a / b`, so the absolute value of the difference `f / divisor - c / 2^24` is bounded below by `1 / (2^24 b)`, so is at least `1 / 2^48` (since `b < 2^24`).  So we're more than `16` double-precision ulps away from any halfway case, and it should be easy to show that the error in the double precision computation can never exceed 16 ulps.  (I haven't done the arithmetic, but I'd guess it's easy to show an upper bound of 3 ulps on the error.)

So `f / divisor` can't be close enough to a halfway case to create problems.  Note that `f / divisor` can't *be* an exact halfway case, either: since `c` is odd, `c` and `2^24` are relatively prime, so the only way we could have `c / 2^24 = a / b` is if `b` is a multiple of `2^24`.  But `b` is in the range `(2^23, 2^24)`, so that's not possible.

The case where `f < divisor` is similar: the halfway cases then have the form `c / 2^25` and the analogous argument shows that `abs(f / divisor - c / 2^25)` is greater than `1 / 2^49`, which again gives us a margin of `16` double-precision ulps to play with.

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly not possible if non-default rounding modes are possible. For example, in replacing `3.0f / 3.0f` with `3.0f * C`, a value of `C` less than the exact reciprocal would yield the wrong result in downward or toward-zero rounding modes, whereas a value of `C` greater than the exact reciprocal would yield the wrong result for upward rounding mode.

It's less clear to me whether what you're looking for is possible if you restrict to default rounding mode. I'll think about it and revise this answer if I come up with anything.

Answer (score 1):

Random search resulted in an example.

Looks like when the result is a "denormal/subnormal" number, the inequality is possible.  But then, maybe my platform is not IEEE 754 compliant?

```
f        0x1.7cbff8p-25 
divisor -0x1.839p+116
q       -0x1.f8p-142
q2      -0x1.f6p-142

int MyIsFinite(float f) {
  union {
    float f;
    unsigned char uc[sizeof (float)];
    unsigned long ul;
  } x;
  x.f = f;
  return (x.ul & 0x7F800000L) != 0x7F800000L;
}

float floatRandom() {
  union {
    float f;
    unsigned char uc[sizeof (float)];
  } x;
  do {
    size_t i;
    for (i=0; i<sizeof(x.uc); i++) x.uc[i] = rand();
  } while (!MyIsFinite(x.f));
  return x.f;
}

void testPC() {
  for (;;) {
    volatile float f, divisor, q, qd;
    do {
      f = floatRandom();
      divisor = floatRandom();
      q = f / divisor;
    } while (!MyIsFinite(q));
    qd = (float) (f * (1.0 / divisor));
    if (qd != q) {
      printf("%a %a %a %a\n", f, divisor, q, qd);
      return;
    }
  }

}
```

Eclipse PC Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426

Comment: `clang -m64 -S` finds that the two computation paths give the same single-precision value for `0x1.7cbff8p-25 / 0x1.839p+116` (`0x1.f8p-142`), and the generated assembly uses the right SSE2 instructions. `clang -m64 -O2 -S` even folds the two computations into the same constant, that it then shares the representation of.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq  Do not know if my platform is 100% IEEE 754.  Note: Interestingly, the `double` result is 0x1.f7p-142.  So the higher precision result is ever so close to half-way between the 2 results I found.  Further: I am now wondering if `f * (1.0 / divisor` was done in even higher precision that IEEE 754 binary64 (double)?  I think C does allow that.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq I am suggesting that your `f * (1.0 / divisor)` is not the same as your posted code: `double factor = 1.0 / divisor; float opt = f * factor;` in that in the second case you force the `factor` to be a `double`.  See C11dr 6.3.1.8 2 Usual arithmetic conversions: "The values of floating operands and of the results of floating expressions may be represented in greater range and precision than that required by the type; the types are not changed thereby."

Comment: about your first comment: Yes, one possibility is for `f * (1.0 / divisor)` to have been compiled at `long double` precision. In an ideal world C compilers would declare their floating-point evaluation strategy by defining `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` to 0, 1, 2 or a negative value. In practice you may not even be able to trust the value that the compiler defines.

Comment: about your second comment: I wrote `f * (1.0 / divisor)` for a {C99,IEEE 754}-compliant C compiler that defines FLT_EVAL_METHOD as 0. For such a compiler the two computations `f * (1.0 / divisor)` and `double factor = 1.0 / divisor; float opt = f * factor;` are identical. This question is not about the vagaries of floating-point in some compilers but about a particular optimization that would be possible in the context of a perfect C99 FLT_EVAL_METHOD=0 compiler. The question **assumes** such a compiler.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq FLT_EVAL_METHOD:"evaluate all operations and constants just to the range and precision of the type". Your question should be applicable if the `1.0` is `binary64` or `binary128`. I am thinking it isn't that the calculation was done in `long double` or `double`. Because either _one_ should have worked, it is that the cast in `(float) (f * (1.0 / divisor))` may have been done is 2 steps (ld->d->f) rather than (ld->f) and _that_ made the difference. (and negating my counter example to your post's assertion). It will be some time before I can dig deeper. Thanks for the poser.