# Does a floating-point reciprocal always round-trip?

Tags: floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy, ieee-754

For IEEE-754 arithmetic, is there a guarantee of 0 or 1 units in the last place accuracy for reciprocals?   From that, is there a guaranteed error-bound on the reciprocal of a reciprocal?

Comment: This question is vaguely related to the question of implementing single-precision multiplication by a constant by a double-precision multiplication by the reciprocal followed by rounding to single-precision, also answered by Mark: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589973/implementing-single-precision-division-as-double-precision-multiplication

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Everything below assumes a fixed IEEE 754 binary format, with some form of round-to-nearest as the rounding-mode.]

Since reciprocal (computed as `1/x`) is a basic arithmetic operation, `1` is exactly representable, and the arithmetic operations are guaranteed correctly rounded by the standard, the reciprocal result is guaranteed to be within `0.5` units in the last place of the true value. (This applies to *any* of the basic arithmetic operations specified in the standard.)

The reciprocal of the reciprocal of a value `x` is not guaranteed to be equal to `x`, in general. A quick example with the IEEE 754 binary64 format:

```
>>> x = 1.8
>>> 1.0 / (1.0 / x)
1.7999999999999998
>>> x == 1.0 / (1.0 / x)
False
```

However, assuming that overflow and underflow are avoided, and that `x` is finite, nonzero, and exactly representable, the following results are true:

1. The value of `1.0 / (1.0 / x)` will differ from `x` by no more than 1 unit in the last place.
2. If the significand of `x` (normalised to lie in the range `[1.0, 2.0)` as usual) is smaller than `sqrt(2)`, then the reciprocal *does* roundtrip: `1.0 / (1.0 / x) == x`.

Sketch of proof: without loss of generality we can assume that `x` is positive, and scale `x` by a power of two so that it lies in the range `[1.0, 2.0)`. The results above are clearly true in the case that `x` is an exact power of two, so let's assume it's not (this will be useful in the second step below). The proof below is given for precision specific to the IEEE 754 binary64 format, but it adapts directly to any IEEE 754 binary format.

Write `1 / x` for the *true* value of the reciprocal, before rounding, and let `y` be the (unique, as it turns out) nearest representable binary64 float to `1 / x`. Then:

- since `y` is the closest float to `1 / x`, and both `y` and `1/x` are in the interval `[0.5, 1.0]`, where the spacing between successive floats is exactly `2^-53`, we have `|y - 1/x| <= 2^-54`. In fact, we can do a bit better:
- we actually have a strict inequality above: `|y - 1/x| < 2^-54`. If `|y - 1/x|` were *exactly* equal to `2^-54`, then `1/x` would be exactly representable in arbitrary-precision binary floating-point (since both `y` and `2^-54` are). But the only binary floats `x` for which `1/x` is exactly representable at some precision are powers of two, and we already excluded this case.
- if `x < sqrt(2)` then `1 / x > x / 2`, hence (rounding both to the nearest representable float), we have `y >= x / 2`, so `x / y <= 2`.
- now `x - 1/y = (y - 1/x) x/y`, and from the bounds on `|y - 1/x|` and `x/y` (still assuming that `x < sqrt(2)`) we get `|x - 1/y| < 2^-53`. It follows that `x` is the closest representable float to `1/y`, `1/y` rounds to `x` and the roundtrip succeeds. This completes the proof of part 2.
- in the general case `x < 2`, we have `x / y < 4`, so `|x - 1/y| < 2^-52`. That makes `1/y` at most 1 ulp away from `x`, which completes the proof of part 1.

Here's a demonstration of the `sqrt(2)` threshold: using Python, we take a million random floats in the range `[1.0, 2.0)`, and identify those that don't roundtrip through the reciprocal. All of the samples smaller than `sqrt(2)` pass the roundtrip.

```
>>> import random
>>> samples = [random.uniform(1.0, 2.0) for _ in range(10**6)]
>>> bad = [x for x in samples if 1.0 / (1.0 / x) != x]
>>> len(bad)
171279
>>> min(bad)
1.4150519879892107
>>> import math
>>> math.sqrt(2)
1.4142135623730951
```

In comments, [@Kelly Bundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057/) finds that the IEEE 754 binary64 value `x` *closest* to √2 for which `1.0 / (1.0 / x) != x` is `0x1.6a09e6964b6acp+0`, or approximately `1.4142135731630487`, roughly `48.6` million ulps away from √2.

And a demonstration that the maximum error is no more than 1 ulp, in general (for the binary64 format, in the interval [1.0, 2.0), 1 unit in the last place is 2^-52):

```
>>> samples = [random.uniform(1.0, 2.0) for _ in range(10**6)]
>>> max(abs(x - 1.0 / (1.0 / x)) for x in samples)
2.220446049250313e-16
>>> 2**-52
2.220446049250313e-16
```

Here's an example with the IEEE 754 binary64 format showing that the restriction about avoiding underflow is necessary:

```
>>> x = 1.3e308
>>> x_roundtrip = 1.0 / (1.0 / x)
>>> x.hex()
'0x1.72409614c1e6ap+1023'
>>> x_roundtrip.hex()
'0x1.72409614c1e6cp+1023'
```

Here the `x_roundtrip` result differs from the original by two units in the last place, because `1 / x` was smaller than the smallest normal representable float, and so was not represented to the same precision as `x`.

Final note: since IEEE 754-2008 covers decimal floating-point types as well, I should mention that the above proof carries over almost verbatim to the decimal case, establishing that for floats with significand smaller than `sqrt(10)`, roundtrip occurs, while for general decimal floats (again avoiding overflow and underflow) we're never off by more than one unit in the last place. However, there's some number-theoretic finesse required to show that the key inequality `|x - 1/y| < 1/2 10^(1-p)` is always strict: one ends up having to show that the quantity `1 + 16 10^(2p-1)` is never a square number (which is true, but it's probably outside the ambit of this site to include the proof here).

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
>>> import random
>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> samples = [+Decimal(random.uniform(1.0, 10.0)) for _ in range(10**6)]
>>> bad = [x for x in samples if 1 / (1 / x) != x]
>>> min(bad)
Decimal('3.16782')
```

Comment: Hmmm... I had to look up "ambit".

Comment: The violator with normalized significand closest to sqrt(2) that I found so far is 6369051721119404 (that [is](https://tio.run/##Lcs9DoAgDEDhnVN0BONfRVEGD@OA0QFtGoZ6esTE@X2PnnTcl12Icz4j3ZwgbulQSmAFZ53vJ5wHRPRjPyri80oaoQONnRijYg2hwG9pdw5CWsyvYjWU2KDJ@QU) 1.4142135731630487 × 2^52) from my [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72885556/12671057). Trying to understand your sqrt proof part now...

Comment: Actually I now think among floats, 1.4142135731630487 is **the** violator closest to sqrt(2). [Brute force search](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v0LBVsFIS0vPlKs8IzMnVQHIt1Uw1Ncw1K/QtOJSAIIKBW2wEl1TI66Cosy8Eo0Kzf//AQ).